# In Excel how to identify the cell location that is partially covered by a picture

Tags: excel

I regularly move images that are positioned at various locations on a spreadsheet usually only partially covering cells. The cell dimensions must be kept constant as their width represents time. I want to know if it is possible to know what cell address is under the right hand side of all images and what the image names are for all images on the spreadsheet.
If I move up to 20 images on the spreadsheet, I would like to be able to run a macro to return the cell address and image name for all moved images.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim s As Shape

For Each s In Me.Shapes
  Debug.Print s.Name, s.BottomRightCell.Address
Next
```